# Searching In DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to search in a data grid via typing in a textbox, but I am unable to find solution.

Do I need to do any binding? If so, then how do I do it?

[image: here's a image]

Comment: which language and tools are you using? We need more information to be able to help you !

Comment: C# and I am using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Please guide about how to bind it , IDK about binding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want filter text in your Datagrid i.e by Name, try this...

```
private bool DataMatchesFilterText(User user, string filterText)
{
    return user.Name.ToString() == filterText;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you will require your data grid to be bound to a Property that contains all your data.
Then add a event handler to your Textbox to act on one of the key events, e.g.
Xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchBox" KeyUp="FilterTextBox_TextChanged" />
```

Then in the code behind you need to act on that event. Here you need to extract the filter text, get the rows in your DataGrid and then perform some method to determine if it should be visible or not. You will need to implement your own DataMatchesFilterText method.

Codebehind:

```
    private void FilterTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var filterTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
        var filterText = filterTextBox.Text;

        SetRowVisibilityByFilterText(filterText);
    }

    private void SetRowVisibilityByFilterText(string filterText)
    {
        GetVisibleRows(yourGrid)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(
            x =>
            {
                if (x == null) return;

                x.Visibility =
                DataMatchesFilterText(x.Item as YourRowProperty, filterText) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            });

    }

    public static IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetVisibleRows(DataGrid grid)
    {
        if (grid == null || grid.Items == null) yield break;
        int count = grid.ItemsSource == null
            ? grid.Items.Count
            : grid.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Count();


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            yield return (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is data matches filter text?

Comment: It is a method that takes in a row and the filter text. You need to implement it yourself and do what ever checks you need to do between the two. For example, if you only want your search to act on the Name column then you'd only compare the name column and filter text in this method.